# Flask NameError: name 'price' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I am trying out a python project for fun where I am trying to return the price of Bitcoin which I scraped from Google onto my Flask app.

This is my error:
`NameError: name 'last_price' is not defined`

I believe I am not pulling the variable correctly in my tracker function in main.py. I think I need some help re-writing how I return the variable, so that it gets pulled into flask.

Here is my main.py:

```
# Import the libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd


# Create a function to get the price of a cryptocurrency
def get_crypto_price(coin):
    # Get the URL
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + coin + "+price"

    # Make a request to the website
    HTML = requests.get(url)

    # Parse the HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the current price
    # text = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd'}).text
    text = soup.find("div", attrs={'class': 'BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd'}).find("div",
                                                                         attrs={'class': 'BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd'}).text
    # Return the text
    return text


# Create a main function to consistently show the price of the cryptocurrency
def tracker():
    # Set the last price to negative one
    last_price = -1
    # Create an infinite loop to continuously show the price
    price = ()
    while True:
        # Choose the cryptocurrency that you want to get the price of (e.g. bitcoin, litecoin)
        crypto = 'bitcoin'
        # Get the price of the crypto currency
        price = get_crypto_price(crypto)
        # Check if the price changed
        if price != last_price:
            print(crypto + ' price: ', price)  # Print the price
            # return price
            last_price = price  # Update the last price
    return price
```

Here is my flask app (app.py):

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
import main

# initializing a variable of Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
# app.secret_key = "secret key"
# app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/home/bobby/zillow_project/'
# app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html', price = price).format()

# run app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my html file (home.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bitcoin's price: {{ price }}</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code using `last_price` seems reasonable. Which line of code is this error happening on? Are you sure this is the exact code? The issue is with `price` perhaps, not `last_price`? And why the infinite loop? Is `price` supposed to be a global in main?

Comment: Add `price = main.tracker()` above the `render_template()` call in the `index()` function.

Comment: @JohnGordon, thanks. I added that piece of code above the `render_template()`, but when I open the Flask App, it seems to be loaded nothing. I think the while function keeps running and this is interfering with the Flask app from loading (because the while loop never finishes). Do you know a way to get constantly updated data into the flask app?